# Algorithm for generating unique value

Tags: java

I want to protect my desktop app which will be distributed by cd. In order to implement idea i have i need to figure out function(algorithm) which will have two parameters cd_key(16 char long) and motherBoard_number(i think 14 char long), and which will return string 16 char long from which i can determine(by reverse engineering) both cd_key and motherBoard_number. Does anyone have idea? I had idea of converting both string to binary then do some operation but i always get string that is longer than 16.

Edit:
When user is performing registration, he enters cd_key, in background i get motherboard serial number and i am sending those two strings to my web service where i have to generate string and send it back to app. Then i write that generated value to registry. The problem is that i have to support offline registration. The idea is that he send me those two values by mail or sms. Again he needs to send me cd_key and motherBoard_number, in order to prevent cheating i need algorithm that will generate value that will user send me by email and based on that value i will get cd_key and motherBoard_number. I would like if that string isn't longer than 16 char.

Comment: Concatenate them, then take a hash, say, MD5

Comment: Do you want symmetric encryption?

Comment: @Blorgbeard Hashing doesn't help if the original values have to be recovered.

Comment: @Tichodroma Uh, whoops, missed that - you're right.

Comment: Please show us what you have [tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). This question is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/on-topic) for StackOverflow.

Comment: Why is the length of the return string limited to 16 characters?

Comment: Please, look at above i edited my question.

Comment: Your edit does not explain why you need to reverse engineer your registration code. See the respective comment to my answer which shows you why you don't need this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, to check the correctness of the license code, you'd not "reverse engineer" the license code, but generate a new one based on the information of the PC the application is running on.

If the generated code matches the code the user entered, the application license is valid.

---

The following scheme is to show the algorithm I've outlined in my comment. As you can see, there's no need at any point to reverse the encoding of the  license code.

[image]

Comment: I thought i wouldn't need to explain everything, and that someone van answer on my question and not suggest other solution, i need offline registration and because of that i need algorithm i asked.

Comment: No you don't need that algorithm. That's what I'm telling you. This has nothing to do with online/offline. We do it as follows: The program gathers some information about the user's PC, combines it into a string and produces an MD5 hash ("hardware key"). We have the user send us that key, we create a registration code from that key and some other information (MD5) and send it back to the user, who enters it in the application. The application also "knows" the information to create the registration code from hardware key and that other information and compares it to the user's code => done.

Comment: Maybe i didn't understand you correctly but i think that this solution doesn't suit my needs because, i am planing to place in market 5000 cd's with 16 char long cd key. If i got your proposal right you give licence/cd_key to user after he sends you hardware hash. Also if i have situation where user is sending me hardware hash by for example with phone call he would need to spell 32 chars, and i would return string of same size which i think is to long.

Comment: The user would give me his CD key and his hardware key, which I'd combine into a license key. The software running on the user's PC would combine CD key and hardware key in the same way and check it against the one entered by the user. As hash algorithms are to provide the same result upon identical input, ideally both keys are the same and the license is valid. About the length: Did you ever activate Windows over phone...?

Comment: Your answer is ok but i have requirement that user can install application offline, actually in my country there are users who doesn't have internet connection so i think that dictating 32 char over phone isn't practical but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A **Java WebStart** distribution channel, so via Internet, would enable a solid safeguard.

Printing separate generated production keys (license numbers) would be a solution too. Offer an update function, so an internet connection allows you to check. The license key could display the user's name in the application. The initial update could free blocked additional functionality.

Comment: I will print separate productions keys and i do online update but i need to support offline registration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want is possible in general, because you will lose information when combining a 16 char string and a 14 string char into one 16 char string.

If you are ok with returning a 30 char string then it is easy or if the alphabet of the returned string can be greater than the input strings. E.g. if the CD key and motherboard number are upper case letters and numbers but the returned string is the full ASCII char set then it might work.